# Filter possible choices for ForeignKey

Tags: django-models, django-forms

Welcome,

I have some problem with limiting choices related with ForeignKey. Below I'm attaching fragment of my code (*models.py*):

```
class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ....

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    ....

class CarForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Car

class DriverForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (DriverForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fileds['car'].queryset = Car.objects.filter(???_1_???)    
    class Meta:
        model = Driver
```

Could anybody give me some advices how should be defined ???*1*??? to restrict available Car objects only to these which aren't assign to any Driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may want to consider changing the relationship between `Car` and `Driver` to a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) rather than a `ForeignKey` if each `Car` can always only have a single `Driver`.

However, if you just want to restrict the choices in the form, your queryset needs to be something like:

```
from django.db.models import Count
self.fields['car'].queryset = Car.objects.annotate(num_drivers=Count('driver')).filter(num_drivers=0)
```